# Can you determine the specific type of device plugged into headphone jack of iphone/ipad/ipod?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, headphones

I have noticed something interesting when working with an iPad and its headphone jack.

I can change the head phone volume (using the volume buttons on the iPad) when I plug in my iPhone earbud headphones into the iPad. If I unplug the earbuds and plug in external speakers using the same headphone jack, I can adjust the volume again, to a different level. If I unplug the speakers, I can replug in the earbuds. The volume automatically changes back to the volume that I had last set the earbuds to. If I have a third device that plugs into the headphone jack (in my case, I tested with a UniMag credit card swipe reader which plugs into the headphone jack) the iPad remembers yet a third volume. It seems to know which device is plugged into the iphone jack and set it to the appropriate volume level.

This is counter to what I expected. I expected there to be one volume level for the headphone jack, without regard to what device is plugged into it.

If the iPad can determine which device is which, is this also available to my native app? Can I tell if the user plugs head phones, external speakers, or a UniMag credit card swipe device into the headphone jack using some Audio API and behave accordingly?

For bonus, if you know the technical mechanism behind the iPads ability to identify which device is which, that would be interesting to me as well.

I am testing on an iPad2 with iOS5.

Comment: Seems to me this would require a private API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CoreAudio for this purpose. I believe you can set up notifications for changes too. More specifically you can do this on iOS with Audio Sessions. What you're looking fo is route changes. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html